# Multiple Pages - Seperate blogs

Tags: posts, pages, blog

I'm struggling to find out the following:

I would like to have 8 different pages (so I have 8 different tabs), and each of them should look like an individual blog.

I can't figure out how to do this, i tried several things such as:

- Creating Categories
- Putting these categories in the menu editor as
  sub pages

But the blogs (posts) keep showing up on the front page.
Website: www.fundamentalblogs.com

Anyone that could help me out? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings in your dashboard and then to "reading" change your homepage to a static page.  This page will then load whenever you load the main site url.

You can then create the other 7 pages and add whatever content you want to those pages.  Make sure if your menu (appearances/menu) isn't adding them to go ahead and add the pages there)

If you need to add individual blog archives to each of the new pages, your theme may have a shortcode or you'll need to run a query for each page and / or setup page templates for each of them.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! Trying it out right now :)

Comment: I can't seem to figure it out.

My Original idea was to have a blank homepage (with some pictures redirecting to the 8 other tabs/blogs).

Now I've made the homepage static it shows all of the blogs, but the tabs aren't showing any. I've added in the menu: 
- Page (tab 1)
    - Sub item Category 1
- Page (tab 2)
    - Sub item Category 2

Comment: What theme are you using?  Does it have a blog shortcode?  What is different about each blog?

Comment: Theme: The Fash Blog. The difference between each blog is the niche, I have large traffic accounts on Instagram which will provide the traffic. This is the website: www.fundamentalblogs.com

Comment: I managed to work it out! I just deleted all the pages and am now working with only categories. I'm just wondering if there is a way to hide the blogs on my home page, since i just want it to be a slideshow

Comment: did you change the blog to a static page still?  You may be able to change the page template to a blank etc, within the page edit screen of the page you chose as homepage.  There will be an option on the right of the page edit screen.

Comment: @robin You can have a lot of categories as a blog and a lot of tabs showing your content; it doesn't matter how much traffic you get from others sites. You must know how the taxonomy URL works to address to the right link to allow WP shows the content (many blogs). for example mysite.com/category1 (blog1), mysite.com/category2/theobvious/ (blog2), mysite.com/category2/payed/ (blog3)